# How to solve the promise for isDisplayed() in protractor

Tags: protractor

Below is my code which return:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
verifyElement(locator){
    var text = element(by.xpath(locator)).isDisplayed()
    text.then(function(result){
        console.log("Element is displayed");
        return true
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("Element is not displayed");
        return false;
    }
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below code. Promise works well with arrow functions.

```
element(by.xpath(locator)).isDisplayed().then(status => {
    if(status){
        //code if element displayed
        assert(true,'Element is displayed');
    }else{
        assert(false,'Element is not being displayed');
    }
});
```

Cheers!